# nanoGallery2 keyword search?

Tags: keyword-search, nanogallery

I am using nanoGallery2 to display my albums from flickr on my own website and
I want to add a search box to my gallery page so visitors can do a keyword search on my photos and display them in an album view.

I's there any way to pass a keyword/filter for searching a flickr gallery album photos tags, title and description in nanoGallery2 ? There only seems to be one for the albums, not the photos as described here: [nanogallery2 - gallery content sources for Flickr](http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/datasource.html#ngy2_flickr)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the API method **`search`**

Example:

`jQuery("#my_nanogallery2").nanogallery2('search', 'YOUR_SEARCH_STRING' );`

where **YOUR_SEARCH_STRING** is the string to search in the thumbnails titles.

You can test it in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/Kris-B/pen/ryOMov)